# using getClass().getResourceAsStream() in servlet to access json file data

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

Hi I have a json file stored in the project folder "project/file.json". How can I first, access and read the json file's data from the servlet's `doGet()`method. Second I want to print the returned data in a separate JSP file. I'm posting here as the last resort since I could not find anything on how to do this. here is my files and my attempt so far

here is file.json

```
{
    "person": {
        "title": "manager",
        "questions": [
            "name ?",
            "age ?",
            "hobby ?"
        ]
    }
}
```

here is the doGet () method from fileServlet.java

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        /* here I'm accessing the external file JSON file*/
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("project/file.json");
        /* here is where I run into trouble. the StringReader() only
        accepts strings and I cannot figure out how to read the table form
        file.json here*/
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(person));

        /*the reader needs to be set inorder to create a JsonObject*/
        JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
    }
```

and finally, the JSP file. I want the file.json items to appear in this form like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            "name ?" get displayed here <br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
            <br>
            "age ?" get displayed here <br>
            <input type="text" name="age" value="">
            <br>
            "hobby ?" get displayed here <br>
            <input type="text" name="hobby" value="">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Done">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help or tips will be appreciated

Comment: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("project/file.json");` - you're not using the return value at all. How do you expect the application will have access to the file contents? Besides that, note that `project/...` implies a source folder. You need to make sure the same path exists at the root of the classpath in any bundled application (e.g. a .war file).

Comment: @Thomas could you demonstrate how what you just explained can be implemented? I'm completely new to this. thank you

Comment: To read the stream, try using `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( getClass().getResourceAsStream("project/file.json") ) );` Make sure to close the reader after reading the resource: `br.close()` or make use of try-with-resources: `try( BufferedReader ...) { /*read here*/ }`.

Comment: @Thomas how can I create a JsonObject from this readers result? thanks

Comment: Did you try passing that BufferedReader to `Json.createReader(...)`?

Comment: @Thomas like so: JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(br); and created the object like so: JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject(); if its correct i still need the display part (second part of my question)

Comment: Well, do you know how to display pojos (or "beans") in a JSP? If no then you might want to grab a tutorial on that, if yes then you should have all you need: either treat that json object as a bean or parse the json into a proper pojo.